# (Responsive jQuery) Div not filling browser height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have made some jQuery full-page sliding panels, which look perfect on desktop, but when the browser is resized down the panel divs don't fill the page.

JSFiddle is the easiest way to view (just resize the preview window down):
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ejqLy/4/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="window">
<div class="panel-1" id="one">
    <p>Lorem</p>
    <div class="nav">Jump To:
       <a href="#" id="1one">1</a>  <a href="#" id="1two">2</a>  <a href="#" id="1three">3</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel-2" id="two">
    <p>Lorem</p>
    <div class="nav">Jump To:
        <a href="#" id="2one">1</a>  <a href="#" id="2two">2</a>  <a href="#" id="2three">3</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel-3" id="three">
    <p>Lorem</p>
    <div class="nav">Jump To:
        <a href="#" id="3one">1</a>  <a href="#" id="3two">2</a>  <a href="#" id="3three">3</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
 }
 .window {
     width: 100%;
     margin: 0 auto;
     overflow: hidden;
     position: fixed;
 }
 [class^="panel"] {
     height: 100%;
     text-align: center;
     position: absolute;
     transition: all ease 1s;
     -o-transition: all ease 1s;
     -moz-transition: all ease 1s;
     -webkit-transition: all ease 1s;
 }
 .panel-1 {
     background: gray;
 }
 .panel-2 {
     background: GoldenRod;
     margin-top:100%;
 }
 .panel-3 {
     background: green;
     margin-top:100%;
 }
```

**JS (jQuery):**

```
// Controls panel movement
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#1two').click(function () {
        $('.panel-2').css('margin-top', '0');
    });
    $('#1three').click(function () {
        $('.panel-3').css('margin-top', '0');
        $('.panel-2').css('margin-top', '0');
    });
    $('#1one').click(function () {
        $('.panel-3').css('margin-top', '100%');
        $('.panel-2').css('margin-top', '100%');
    });
    $('#2two').click(function () {
        $('.panel-2').css('margin-top', '0');
    });
    $('#2three').click(function () {
        $('.panel-3').css('margin-top', '0');
    });
    $('#2one').click(function () {
        $('.panel-3').css('margin-top', '100%');
        $('.panel-2').css('margin-top', '100%');
    });
    $('#3two').click(function () {
        $('.panel-2').css('margin-top', '0');
        $('.panel-3').css('margin-top', '100%');
    });
    $('#3three').click(function () {
        $('.panel-3').css('margin-top', '0');
    });
    $('#3one').click(function () {
        $('.panel-3').css('margin-top', '100%');
        $('.panel-2').css('margin-top', '100%');
    });
});

// Forces "window" <div> to full page height
$(function () {
    $('.window').css({
        'height': (($(window).height())) + 'px'
    });
    $(window).resize(function () {
        $('.window').css({
            'height': (($(window).height())) + 'px'
        });
    });
});
```

Any help will be much appreciated! [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ejqLy/4/)

Comment: The height of the div looks okay, but your .nav needs to be positioned to the bottom, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ejqLy/6/

Comment: you can checkout fullPage.js a jquery plugin that just does what you are looking for. http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/

Comment: @Nirus Or we could, you know, just solve the problem.

Comment: @Nirus comment is a fair one, if he had posted it as an answer it would be worth criticising.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is being caused by the use of `margin-top` to animate and position the panels on/off screen.  Because the panels are all absolutely positioned you can just use the `top` declaration, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#1two').click(function () {
        $('.panel-2').css('top', '0');
    });
    $('#1three').click(function () {
        $('.panel-3').css('top', '0');
        $('.panel-2').css('top', '0');
    });
    $('#1one').click(function () {
        $('.panel-3').css('top', '100%');
        $('.panel-2').css('top', '100%');
    });
    $('#2two').click(function () {
        $('.panel-2').css('top', '0');
    });
    $('#2three').click(function () {
        $('.panel-3').css('top', '0');
    });
    $('#2one').click(function () {
        $('.panel-3').css('top', '100%');
        $('.panel-2').css('top', '100%');
    });
    $('#3two').click(function () {
        $('.panel-2').css('top', '0');
        $('.panel-3').css('top', '100%');
    });
    $('#3three').click(function () {
        $('.panel-3').css('top', '0');
    });
    $('#3one').click(function () {
        $('.panel-3').css('top', '100%');
        $('.panel-2').css('top', '100%');
    });
});
```

Also, be sure to update your CSS:

```
 .panel-1 {
     background: gray;
 }
 .panel-2 {
     background: GoldenRod;
     top:100%;
 }
 .panel-3 {
     background: green;
    top: 100%;
 }
/* Nav */
 .nav {
    background:black;
    color:yellow;
    bottom:0;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
}
```

Here's your updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ejqLy/7/)

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have updated the fiddle. just check if it works as intended

http://jsfiddle.net/ejqLy/8/

```
 .nav {
background:black;
color:yellow;
bottom:0;
position:absolute;
width:100%;
```

}

With Shuffle animation:

[JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ejqLy/11/)

Answer (score -1):

The height of the div looks okay, but your `.nav` needs to be positioned to the bottom, like this: [jsfiddle.net/ejqLy/6](http://jsfiddle.net/ejqLy/6)

Comment: Doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: You're right @monners my screen was too small to show the actual issue that was being referenced.